# Checking a valid names in text file

Tags: c#, text

Is there any way to check and validate in a text file that it contains any human name. For example I have a text file and it contain my name somewhere in file as "Muhammad Hannan" or any other. How I am able to find and check this for any unknown text file.

EDIT:

I don't have any list of name from which I have to compare. I have only some of text file may be thousands of them and I have to check and validate that the files contain any human name[In English only].

Comment: Do you have a list of people to compare against? After all, there are people named [Moon Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_Zappa).

Comment: Wait, do you want to check that it contains a *specific* name or that it contains some human being's name?

Comment: Is it a text file or binary file? if it is text file then what is the encoding?

Comment: Please explain your question properly. What _exactly_ do you want to do? How do you recognize a "name"? What is "any unknown flie"?

Comment: That it contain any human name @aquinas

Comment: Got it. That's impossible, since people can call themselves anything they want. Example, I could legally change my name to "This Is Not My Name"

Comment: This is impossible. A human name can be anything, from 姓 to Bieber, or [Hashtag](http://www.cnet.com/news/proud-parents-name-child-hashtag/).

Comment: So there is no way to do that? No way for some valid name also? @aquinas

Comment: Build a database with every name given to every person ever... I'll wait til you finish.

Comment: Suppose I have database containing list of valid names and I will search for every name and match it to my file ok fine. But what if I have ten thousand of files and at least 5 million people names in database what will I do ? @crashmstr

Comment: Well, you need to keep going and add more names to the database, since there were people born in the last 7 minutes. The whole point is that your list will never be complete.

Comment: That's a tough job. Any way to match faster. File contain a name from the list.@crashmstr

Comment: Can you explain what you *ultimately* are trying to accomplish? Is your task literally, "Given a file, this will tell you if someone in the world has a name in that file?" I doubt it. What is your END goal?

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a list of names entered by users, and that you wish to "validate" this list.

You have to understand you cannot solve this problem. There is no such thing as a "valid" human name. Read the blog [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) for a list of 40 common misconceptions found often in code.

You may think "Asdfg Hjkl" is not a valid name, even though it's the most common name after "Abc 123" according to many surveys, but perhaps right this instance someone is registering their child with this name.

There [are lists of names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803628/raw-list-of-person-names) that you can compare against. Then all you can do is manually inspect each entry that you have which isn't on any list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "any unknown file". Also, some code for what you have tried to do so far would be extremely helpful. Using the following:

```
bool hasName;
using(var tempReader = new StreamReader(fileLocation))
{
    hasName = tempReader.ReadToEnd().Contains("My Name");
}
```

will return true if a text file contains "My Name" (case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

this problem is called "Named Entity Recognition"